# Proving that a function is an isomorphism of groups

Tags: group-isomorphism, function-and-relation-composition

Let A and B be non-empty sets and *f* : **A** → **B** be a bijection. Consider the map $\phi$ : $S_A$ → $S_B$ that sends $\sigma$ to ${f} \circ {\sigma} \circ {f^{-1}}$. Show that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of groups.

Help. Thanks!

Comment: Just follow the definitions. Where are you stuck?

Comment: To prove that it is 1-1, I let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in S_A$. Then $\phi(\sigma_1)  = \phi(\sigma_2)$ implies that  ${f} \circ {\sigma_1} \circ {f^{-1}} = {f} \circ {\sigma_2} \circ {f^{-1}}$. Now I don't know how to show that $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$.

Comment: In ${f} \circ {\sigma_1} \circ {f^{-1}} = {f} \circ {\sigma_2} \circ {f^{-1}}$, apply $f^{-1}$ on the left and $f$ on the right.

Comment: you have to prove that $\phi$ is a bijection $S_A \to S_B$, but also that it is a group morphism.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is a bijection, $|A|=|B|$ so $|S_A|=|S_B|$. If $\varphi(\sigma)=\varphi(\sigma')$, then $$f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1}=f\circ\sigma'\circ f^{-1}, $$ so applying $f^{-1}$ on the left and $f$ on the right yields $\sigma=\sigma'$. If $\tau\in B$, then $f^{-1}\circ\tau\circ f\in A$ and $$\tau=\varphi(f^{-1}\circ\tau\circ f), $$ and hence $\varphi$ is a bijection. Now given $\sigma,\sigma'\in A$, we have
$$\varphi(\sigma\sigma') = f\circ(\sigma\sigma')\circ f^{-1}=(f\circ\sigma\circ f^{-1})\circ(f\circ\sigma'\circ f^{-1})=\varphi(\sigma\sigma'), $$ so that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.